# RabbitListener returning String as ASCII instead of String

Tags: spring-integration, spring-amqp

For some reason RabbitListener is showing the ASCII representation instead of actual string

> Rabbit MQ Message
>
> Exchange  raw-cdr
>
> Routing Key   uk
>
> Redelivered
>   priority: 0
>
> delivery_mode:    2
>
> headers:
>
> > file_name:    /Users/shahbour/IdeaProjects/micro-services/file-sftp-service/ftp-inbound/LONSBC01.20161214142000.10120CB.ACT
> >
> > content_encoding: UTF-8
> >
> > content_type: text/plain
>
> Sonus Networks, Inc.00000000FF600000520000000000000128V04.02.05R000
>   0000000000000000000000000000ACT2016121414100000000000000000

but what i got is

> 83,111,110,117,115,32,78,101,116,119,111,114,107,115,44,32,73,110,99,46,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,70,70,54,48,48,48,48,48,53,50,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,49,50,56,86,48,52,46,48,50,46,48,53,82,48,48,48,32,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,65,67,84,50,48,49,54,49,50,49,52,49,52,49,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48

Below is the code i am using , every thing is spring boot default

```
@RabbitListener(queues = {"fr-cdr.panel","uk-cdr.panel"})
public void messageHandler(Message<String> rawCdr, @Header String file_name) throws InterruptedException {
    log.info(rawCdr);

}
```

the producer is from another program as below

```
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "linesChannel")
    public AmqpOutboundEndpoint amqpOutbound(AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
        AmqpOutboundEndpoint outbound = new AmqpOutboundEndpoint(amqpTemplate);
        outbound.setExchangeName(exchangeName);
        outbound.setRoutingKey(routingKey);
        return outbound;
    }
```

After enabling debug mode the problem shows

```
2016-12-16 07:46:03.714 DEBUG 81519 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Received message: (Body:'Sonus Networks, Inc.00000000FF600000520000000000000128V04.02.05R000 0000000000000000000000000000ACT2016121414100000000000000000' MessageProperties [headers={file_name=/Users/shahbour/IdeaProjects/micro-services/file-sftp-service/ftp-inbound/LONSBC01.20161214142000.10120CB.ACT}, timestamp=null, messageId=null, userId=null, receivedUserId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, type=null, correlationId=null, correlationIdString=null, replyTo=null, contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=null, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=0, redelivered=true, receivedExchange=raw-cdr, receivedRoutingKey=uk, receivedDelay=null, deliveryTag=1, messageCount=0, consumerTag=amq.ctag-15IUBH6oN_hheTvluP4YfQ, consumerQueue=uk-cdr.panel])
2016-12-16 07:46:03.717  WARN 81519 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.s.c.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter   : Could not convert incoming message with content-type [text/plain]
2016-12-16 07:46:03.724 DEBUG 81519 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] .a.r.l.a.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Processing [GenericMessage [payload=byte[127], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=uk, amqp_contentEncoding=UTF-8, amqp_receivedExchange=raw-cdr, amqp_deliveryTag=1, file_name=/Users/shahbour/IdeaProjects/micro-services/file-sftp-service/ftp-inbound/LONSBC01.20161214142000.10120CB.ACT, amqp_consumerQueue=uk-cdr.panel, amqp_redelivered=true, id=c645580a-6f8d-6649-1426-14d06fbc1ddf, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-15IUBH6oN_hheTvluP4YfQ, contentType=text/plain, timestamp=1481867163721}]]
```

After commenting out the below Jackson2JsonMessageConverter every thing worked perfectly.

```
    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jackson2json() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }
```

Even though in warning it was declaring that it can't convert

Comment: Please show your listener container factory bean; also turn on DEBUG logging, if you can't figure it out from the log, post the log someplace so we can take a look.

Comment: @GaryRussell should having `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` declared result in the above effect or it is a bug ?

Comment: Yes; see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot will auto-configure the listener container adapter's message converter if a single bean of type `MessageConverter` is declared in the application context.

That converter expects a content type of `application/json`.

If you have some messages that are `text/plain` and some that are `application/json`, you should configure a `ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter` with a `SimpleMessageConverter` and the JSON converter.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation